# How can I run / record an iOS app in the XCode 6 iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, video, simulator

I might be going about this wrong, but I am trying to run an iOS app in the Xcode 6 iOS simulator in order to record a video tutorial of the app. 
I have xCode installed and can launch the iOS simulator, but there seems to be no way to install an .app file. The ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator folder is a complete mystery and there is no clear location to drop the app files.

Any ideas?

Alternatively, is there an easier way to record a video of your iOS app? People must do it all the time for tutorials...

Thanks

Comment: If it's your iOS app, you have the code and your can build & run the app by xCode? You can record the simulator by using some software like http://screenyapp.com or directly on your phone with something like http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/record-your-ipads-iphones-screen-no-jailbreak-computer-required-0156864/ ...

Comment: You can use this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792488/recording-iphone-screen-while-running-app-on-xcode/55843630#55843630)

Comment: May you can use this easist [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792488/recording-iphone-screen-while-running-app-on-xcode/55843630#55843630)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you were running the app on a device, you could use the new Yosemite feature to record over USB to QuickTime.

However, as you are using the simulator, you will need to a partial screen recording in QuickTime.

## Using QuickTime

Launch QuickTime then go to File > New Screen Recording. You can either click to select the whole screen, or drag to only record a portion of the screen.

[image]

## Alternatives

If you want more flexibility, you will need to use 3rd party software like [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm).

Comment: Right, it couldn't be easier. Just use QuickTime. A little-known feature!

Comment: Just wanted to call out that the small point above that this is way easier if you record from the device instead of the simulator: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/

Answer (score 4):

From **Xcode 8.2**,You can take a screenshot or record a video of the simulator window using the **xcrun command-line utility**.

```
Launch your app in Simulator.
Launch Terminal (located in /Applications/Utilities), and enter the appropriate command:
To take a screenshot, use the screenshot operation:
xcrun simctl io booted screenshot

You can specify an optional filename at the end of the command.

To record a video, use the recordVideo operation:
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo <filename>.<extension>

To stop recording, press Control-C in Terminal.

Note: You must specify a filename for recordVideo.
The default location for the created file is the current directory.
For more information on simctl, run this command in Terminal:

xcrun simctl help

For more information on the io subcommand of simctl, run this command:

xcrun simctl io help
```

Check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH3-SW4) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Build & Run' in Xcode to install and run your app in the iOS Simualtor.

Alternatively, you can run `xcrun simctl install <Device UDID> <Path to app>` to install your app.  See `xcrun simctl help` for more information.

Regarding recording a screen capture video, you should use QuickTime.