# How to record iPhone screen during app testing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testing, screen

I'm developing an app and need to record the iPhone screen while it's running in Xcode for testing purposes. This would help correlate user actions with Xcode outputs and logs. Are there any software tools that can facilitate this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Option 1: USB cable + QuickTime on Mac

1. Connect the iPhone/iPad to a Mac using an USB cable
2. Open QuickTime, select "File > New Screen Recording"

[image: New Screen Recording]

3. Press a small arrow next to the recording button and choose "Screen > (your mobile device)"

[image: Device screen]

4. You can start recording now!

#### Option 2: Recording directly on the mobile device (iOS 11+)

1. Launch Settings, select Control Center
2. Add Screen Recording
3. Swipe-up from the bottom of the display to reveal Control Center
4. Tap the "Screen Recording" button.

[image: Screen Recording button]

Comment: I thought it would be a dedicated software for this function but anyway it makes what I need. Thanks!

Comment: For more functionality there is also the 3rd party software [Screenflow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm).

Comment: On iOS 11 simulation not have Control Center

Comment: @ArNo, do you mean iOS simulator? The question (and the edit) concern the iPhone (or iPad) devices, if you want to record the simulator screen you must use quicktime.

Answer (score 8):

Use QuickTimePlayer:

1. Connect iDevice to Mac.
2. Open QuickTime
3. File > New Movie Recording
4. If you don't see your screen mirrored immediately, go to the dropdown arrow next to the record button and select Camera > iDevice

If you are recording from iOS Simulator:

1. Start everything up in iOS Simulator
2. Open QuickTime
3. File > New Screen Recording
4. Press record button. You will now be given the option to drag out an area of the screen to record.

Comment: Note: IME using QuickTime causes my device to disconnect from the debugger.

Answer (score 6):

To take a screenshot, use the screenshot operation:

```
xcrun simctl io booted screenshot
```

To record a video, use the recordVideo operation:

```
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo <VideoFILENAME>.<extension>
```

**UPDATE**

Using the new release of Xcode 12.5 you can simply record the simulator screen using **⌘ + R**.

or as bellow:

1. Launch Simulator app.
2. Open File menu > Record Screen

[image]

3. Recording indicator will show up on the upper right of the title bar. You can begin your recording after the indicator showing up.
   [image]

[source](https://sarunw.com/posts/record-ios-simulator-video-and-gif-with-xcode/)

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered in this forum at this post

[Capture iOS Simulator video for App Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797990/capture-ios-simulator-video-for-app-preview)

Anyways, you can use [QuickTime](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/) recorder to record your app running on the iPhone